# Native Query, make WHERE conditionial if a parameter is null or empty

Tags: sql, jpa, where-clause

i'm having an issue with my query in my spring boot/angular app, using @Query.

```
@Query(value =" SELECT "
            + " flow.ID, "
            + " min(flow.CONTEXTTIMESTAMP) contextTime,  "
            + " state.LOGROLE, "
            + " trait.ETAT, "
            + " CONCAT(' ',CONCAT(ac.NAME, CONCAT('=',ac.VALUE))) as idf "
            + "FROM "
            + "FLOW flow "
            + "INNER JOIN LOG trc ON flow.ID= trc.ID"
            + "INNER JOIN APPLICATION ac ON flow.ID= ac.ID"
            + "LEFT OUTER JOIN PROCESS trait ON flow.ID= trait.ID"
            + "LEFT OUTER JOIN STATE state ON flow.ID= state.ID"
            + "WHERE  "
            +" flow.FLOWCODE = ?3 "
            + "AND flow.CONTEXTTIMESTAMP BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2 "
            + "AND  CONCAT(' ',CONCAT(ac.NAME, CONCAT('=',ac.VALUE))) = ?4  "
            + "AND trait.etat = ?5 "
            + "AND trc.LOGROLE =  ?6  "
            + "GROUP BY "  
            + "flow.ID, "
            + "state.LOGROLE, "
            + "trait.ETAT, " 
            + "ac.NAME, " 
            + "ac.VALUE "
            + "ORDER BY  " + " contextTime desc, flow.ID, idf ", nativeQuery = true)
            public  List <FlowDto> fetchAllProcessContextWithCriteria(
            String startDate, String endDate, String flowCode,String idf,  String etat, String status );
```

Some parameters of my method could be null or empty in some case, since they are coming from my angular form.
I would like to igore the WHERE clause for this parameters if they are empty or null( idf or status for instance), cant figure to do it actually.

By the way, if you have any idea or advice to optimize the query, i will be please to hear :)

Have a great day everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you can try something like this.

> (flow.FLOWCODE = ?3 OR ?3 IS NULL)

```
@Query(value =" SELECT "
        + " flow.ID, "
        + " min(flow.CONTEXTTIMESTAMP) contextTime,  "
        + " state.LOGROLE, "
        + " trait.ETAT, "
        + " CONCAT(' ',CONCAT(ac.NAME, CONCAT('=',ac.VALUE))) as idf "
        + "FROM "
        + "FLOW flow "
        + "INNER JOIN LOG trc ON flow.ID= trc.ID"
        + "INNER JOIN APPLICATION ac ON flow.ID= ac.ID"
        + "LEFT OUTER JOIN PROCESS trait ON flow.ID= trait.ID"
        + "LEFT OUTER JOIN STATE state ON flow.ID= state.ID"
        + "WHERE  "
        +" (flow.FLOWCODE = ?3 OR ?3 IS NULL) "
        + "AND flow.CONTEXTTIMESTAMP BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2 "
        + "AND  CONCAT(' ',CONCAT(ac.NAME, CONCAT('=',ac.VALUE))) = ?4  "
        + "AND ( trait.etat = ?5 OR ?5 IS NULL)"
        + "AND ( trc.LOGROLE = ?6 OR ?6 IS NULL)"
        + "GROUP BY "  
        + "flow.ID, "
        + "state.LOGROLE, "
        + "trait.ETAT, " 
        + "ac.NAME, " 
        + "ac.VALUE "
        + "ORDER BY  " + " contextTime desc, flow.ID, idf ", nativeQuery = true)
        public  List <FlowDto> fetchAllProcessContextWithCriteria(
        String startDate, String endDate, String flowCode,String idf,  String etat, String status );
```

Good luck!